# Filter without duplicates and add to listbox column 1

Tags: excel, vba

This code works to find the first value, I'm needing it to capture the first cell which contains "120" in it, which means 120, 7120, 31200 all of which contains duplicates. Also, ID CODE is in column C, how do I add data in column D into the second column of the listbox?

```
Dim AGCN As Long
Dim AGCL As String
Dim AGNN As Long
Dim AGNL As String
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim AGC As Range
Dim AGN As Range
Dim firstaddress As Long
Dim nextaddress As Long

'Identify column letter
AGCN = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="ID CODE", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
AGCL = Split(Cells(1, AGCN).Address, "$")(1)

AGNN = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="NAME", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
AGNL = Split(Cells(1, AGNN).Address, "$")(1)


With Sheet1.Range(AGCL & ":" & AGCL)
    Set c = .Find("*" & tbAC & "*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = c.Value
        Debug.Print firstaddress
            With Me.ListBox2
           .ColumnCount = 3
           .ColumnWidths = "50;150;70"
           .AddItem
           .List(i, 0) = Str(firstaddress)
           i = o + 1
           End With ' code works up till this part

    Do ' from here, 
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo donefinding
        ElseIf firstaddress <> c.Value Then
            nextaddress = c.Value
            Debug.Print nextaddress
            With Me.ListBox2
                .ColumnCount = 3
                .ColumnWidths = "50;150;70"
                .AddItem
                .List(i, 0) = Str(nextaddress)
                Debug.Print nextaddress
                i = o + 1
            End With
        End If
    Loop While c.Address <> firstaddress ' till here, it loops through all the other possible values but does not input onto listbox and it crashes my excel

End If
donefinding: Exit Sub
End With
```

There's currently no error messages, excel just loops and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The `.List(i, 0) = ...` will crash if the value of `o + 1` is larger than the count of listbox items, but that would happen right in the 1st loop.

Otherwise you use `i = o + 1` in each loop so the value of `i` does not change so you keep overwriting the same item in the listbox. So the count of listbox items grows in every loop but  you can see only the latest value in the 1st position (I assume the value of `o` is 0).

Other suggestions:
You can simplify initiation of `.Find` like this:

```
AGCN = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="ID CODE", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
With Sheet1.Columns(AGCN)
     Set c = .Find(tbAC, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)   ' you can omit "*" by using xlPart
     ...
```

You can address 2nd, 3rd, etc. columns in the listbox by considering it a 0 based "array":

```
.List(i, 1) = "Something"    ' will put "Something" to column 2
.List(i, 2) = "Anything"    ' will put "Anything" to column 3
```

You don't need to repeat setting `.ColumnCount` and `.ColumnWidths` in every loop.